# "Maximum update depth exceeded ..." when parent callback is called in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I still don't get why I'm getting an update depth exceeded on this specific case, i would appreciate if any help is given.

To give some insight.

I got a Parent and a Child (multi-list selector) component that I created.
This multi-list allows you to select multiple items and when modal is closed, I execute a callback that comes from Parent, with the list of items selected and update it from the Parent itself by doing setState.

On Parent's constructor I got the callback function like this:

**Parent**

`this.onItemSelected = this.onItemSelected.bind(this);`

This is the function above:

```
onItemSelected(updatedList) {
    this.setState({selectedItemList: updatedList});
}
```

This is when I use it and pass it to Children.

```
renderModalMultiSelect = () => {
        return (
            <MultiSelect
                items={this.state.itemList}
                onItemSelect={ this.onItemSelected }
                disabled={this.state.filters.type === 'all'}
                isLoadingList={this.state.isLoadingList}
            />
        )
    }
```

Of course this is on Parent's render() function as `{ this.renderModalMultiSelect() }`

**Children**

On this component, I handle the selected item list locally, is not on the State, so whenever I press on items, I just simply do a push on this local array.
When I close the modal, I run the parent props callback.

```
onClose = () => {
        this.setState({ modalOpened: false }, () => {
            // Optional callback
            if (this.props.onItemSelect) {
                this.props.onItemSelect(this.selectedItems);
            }
        })
    }
```

Again, this function is used on children's render()

```
<Button onPress={ this.onClose } transparent>
    <Icon name="md-arrow-back" style={ styles.headerIcon }/>
</Button>
```

Before this, I was passing a state from Parent to Children with the list of selected items, but it didn't seem right to do things like: `this.props.selectedItemList.push(item)` or is this fine to do?

Thanks and I hope I can understand what's going on here, it keeps throwing this error whenever I close the modal (onClose is called).

Comment: It's hard to specify the problem. Show me the whole code.

Comment: It ended up being something related to a different function on render() that i modified yesterday by removing the arrow function on it, can't believe it, i feel so dumb, i spent like 4 hours trying to find the problem.

Comment: I'm glad the problem is solved. Note that the arrow function causes a lot of rendering, so it is not recommended to use it unless you need them. It make apps slower.

Comment: oh wow and what should i use instead??

Comment: @hongdevelop dunno if you received the notification hehehe, but i would really like to know how can i make my app more optimized by reducing the amount of arrow functions